# input-to-hidden layer weight update, multilayer Perceptron neural net

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I was trying to implement a simple multilayer neural net to solve the XOR, its just to learn how multilayer nets and weight updates works.
I came up with the matlab code and its working fine and gets good results,
but the part that updates the input-to-hidden layer weights its seems wrong,
because it multiplies hidden layer deltas by wrong input, in this part of code:

```
    w1(1) = w1(1) + learnRate * (delta2(1) * neur1(1));
    w1(2) = w1(2) + learnRate * (delta2(1) * neur1(1));
    w1(3) = w1(3) + learnRate * (delta2(2) * neur1(2));
    w1(4) = w1(4) + learnRate * (delta2(2) * neur1(2));
```

I think this should change to:

```
    w1(1) = w1(1) + learnRate * (delta2(1) * neur1(1));
    w1(2) = w1(2) + learnRate * (delta2(1) * neur1(2));
    w1(3) = w1(3) + learnRate * (delta2(2) * neur1(1));
    w1(4) = w1(4) + learnRate * (delta2(2) * neur1(2));
```

can any one explain why it fails when I do the change?!

complete code (which works but seems wrong):

```
clear
clc

maxIt = 3000;

%% Neural Net initialize

neur1 = zeros(2,1);
neur2 = zeros(2,1);
neur3 = 0;

out2 = zeros(2,1);
out3 = 0;

out = zeros(4,1);
outCount = 1;

% weights ()
w1 = zeros(4,1) + 0.2;
w2 = zeros(2,1) + 0.2;
b1 = zeros(2,1) + 0.2;
b2 = 0.2;

desired = [0; ...
           1; ...
           1; ...
           0; ];

learnRate = 0.7;

input = [0 0;0 1;1 0;1 1];

ETotal = zeros(maxIt,1);

%% Main Loop

for iteration = 1 : maxIt

for dataCount = 1 : 4

    neur1 = input(dataCount,:)';


    neur2(1) = neur1(1) * w1(1) + neur1(2) * w1(2) + 1 * b1(1);
    neur2(2) = neur1(1) * w1(3) + neur1(2) * w1(4) + 1 * b1(2);
    out2(1) = 1./(1+exp(-neur2(1)));
    out2(2) = 1./(1+exp(-neur2(2)));

    neur3 = out2(1) * w2(1) + out2(2) * w2(2) + 1 * b2;
    out3 = 1./(1+exp(-neur3));

    %% Backpropagation

    out(dataCount) = out3;

    %delta
    err = desired(dataCount) - out3;
    delta3 = err * (out3 * (1 - out3));

    delta2(1) = (delta3 * w2(1)) * (out2(1) * (1 - out2(1)));
    delta2(2) = (delta3 * w2(2)) * (out2(2) * (1 - out2(2)));

    %weight update
    w2(1) = w2(1) + learnRate * (delta3 * out2(1));
    w2(2) = w2(2) + learnRate * (delta3 * out2(2));
    b2 = b2 + learnRate * (delta3 * 1);   %bias weight update

    w1(1) = w1(1) + learnRate * (delta2(1) * neur1(1));
    w1(2) = w1(2) + learnRate * (delta2(1) * neur1(1));
    w1(3) = w1(3) + learnRate * (delta2(2) * neur1(2));
    w1(4) = w1(4) + learnRate * (delta2(2) * neur1(2));
    b1(1) = b1(1) + learnRate * (delta2(1) * 1);
    b1(2) = b1(2) + learnRate * (delta2(2) * 1);

    fprintf('%.5f - ', out3);
    %fprintf('[%.10f,%.10f]-- ', w2(1), w2(2));
end
ETotal(iteration) = mse(out,desired);
outCount = 1;

%fprintf('\n %i -- %.20f \n', iteration, ETotal(iteration) );
fprintf('\n');
end

plot(ETotal);
```

This net has 2 inputs (neur1) and 2 perceptron in hidden layer (neur2) and one perceptron as output (neur3)

out2,3 are output of each perceptron using sigmoid

w1,w2 as weights and b1,b2 as bias

[image: network design image]

Thanks.

Comment: Tell us about what each variable is, or how they relate to the structure of the net you have, please

Comment: I have updated my question with more info, its a simple net with 1 hidden layer (2 perceptrons) and 1 perceptron  as output

Comment: so `w1(4)` corresponds to the weigths of the fourth neuron (output neuron)? and `w2(4)`? Take your time to really explain all these

Comment: added network design image